# Populating a vector of objects within a class

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, struct

and I've hit my first wall on my coding project/assignment.

I'm to implement functionality into code that's been done to some stage, and I cannot alter the given code so I have to work around the given structure.

The code, in a nutshell, reads family relations from a text file and populates database with the family relation data and later on allows user to print out information he wants to access.

What I'm having trouble with is understanding how I can and how I have to utilize a `struct` given to me in the assignment. The struct is

```
struct Person
{
    std::string id_ = NO_ID;
    int height_ = NO_HEIGHT;
    std::vector<Person*> parents_{nullptr, nullptr};
    std::vector<Person*> children_;
};
```

and I'm using it at least in the initialization phase of the data structure.

I start by calling the process in main.cpp with

```
database->addRelation(it->child_, it->parents_, std::cout);
```

In the naming/height adding phase I'd simply do it with

```
MyPerson.id_ = id;
MyPerson.height_ = height;
```

where `MyPerson` is defined by `Person MyPerson;`

but as far as I can tell, I have to somehow access the object pointers to be able to populate the vectors for when I want to add children/parents to the person.

The class functions that are called when initializing person's name, height and family relations are these two:

```
void Familytree::addNewPerson(const string &id, const int &height, ostream &output)
{
    MyPerson.id_ = id;
    MyPerson.height_ = height;
}

void Familytree::addRelation(const string &child,
                             const std::vector<string>
                             &parents, ostream &output)
{

}
```

The addRelation fuction is what I'm having a hard time getting to work. Simply appending the strings to it won't work since it expects Person* -objects, which are, as far as I can tell, just pointers to the other Persons, but I'm not sure how I can access them.

Also, let me know if anything here is excessive or if I'm missing anything crucial, I'll edit it to the best of my ability

Editing with additional information:

The only things I've added myself that can be seen here is 
`Person MyPerson;`

and the contents of the class function `addNewPerson`. The other snippets I can not change in any shape or form.

Edit#2

Current progress, debatable whether I'm closer or further from the goal

My persons map is `using Personmap = std::map<std::string, Person >;`

and I'm using it in addNewPerson with

```
persons_[id] = id;
persons_[id] = height;
```

, but I'm still randomly trying different things to try and make it work for the next phase where I need to somehow add the objects to the vectors.

The biggest problem I have is the fact that I do now know how to play around the difference of `*Person` and `Person`

Comment: The vectors both store pointers so you're going to need another container somewhere to store the actual objects (so that you can then put pointers to these objects in the two vectors). It seems like a strange design.

Comment: its rather unclear what is the code that you need to write and what is the code that you are not supposed to modify. Are you allowed to change parameters of `FamilyTree::addRelation` ?

Comment: Looks like your `parents_` vector links to other `Person`s via pointers, therefore it is unclear what you are trying to achieve by passing strings? Are they IDs? If they are then you have to search all your `Person`s for the IDs and return pointers to those persons and then populate `parents_` with valid pointers.

Comment: @JonathanPotter what do pointers in C++ look like? I was able to trace with debug mode that it does have stuff like "@0x1becc20" in the intitialization phase that I don't do anything with (though it's not "string")

@user463035818 No, the parameters for the functions cannot be changed in this assignment. The only things that I've done myself so far is the contents of addNewPerson function and adding "`Person MyPerson;` to the header of the class file 

@KillzoneKid so I can build an iterator function that iterates through MyPerson(?) and returns a pointer when the correct ID is found?

Comment: @Grak No, you have to iterate through **all** persons. I don't know if you have a container that holds all people or you have entry point from which you can navigate all relations to find people, but either way it sounds unnecessarily complicated. EDIT I see you have `Familytree` class of which you showed nothing, my bet you should have some kind of method in it to help you.

Comment: Something like PersonMap = map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Person>; where the key would be the name of the person it points to? I think I understand your suggestion but I'm a bit lost on the implementation side, but I'll try testing different kinds of stuff until it works

Comment: @Grak something like that, but then why are you mixing shared_ptr and raw pointers?

Comment: That was just something that had been in the code beforehand, but I don't think I have to use that structure so I can do it without a shared pointer. The assignment is quite tricky for me since it has so much stuff in it and even figuring out what I have to use and what I don't need to use is a chore