# C++ what is the difference between "Obj" and "Obj*" and how can I know when to use which?

Tags: c++, pointers, object

Sorry for the messy title, I'm not quite sure how I should word it to better get my meaning across.

So, I have

```
struct Person
{
    std::string id_ = NO_ID;
    int height_ = NO_HEIGHT;
    std::vector<Person*> parents_{nullptr, nullptr};
    std::vector<Person*> children_;
};
```

and I want to be able to populate a map of Person(s) with data.

I made

```
using Personmap = std::map<std::string, Person >;
```

for it, but I'm not sure whether I should use `*Person` or `Person` here.

When I use `Person`, I at least know how to work with it, but when I try populating the vectors with data using anything like

```
    persons_[child].parents_[0]  = ( persons_[parent_1] );
```

or similar, I'm getting an error because I'm trying to populate it with `Person` instead of `Person*`. Apart from the error message, I don't quite understand their difference and I'm not sure what I should utilize to make it work. The struct is not something I can change, but anything else here is free for scrutiny

Comment: Perhaps you need [a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read about pointers?

Comment: Chances are you don't need a vector of pointers.

Comment: [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5727/995714), [When to use pointers, and when not to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1327943/995714)

Comment: The whole idea to have parents and children as pointers so that they point to other structures of people. Where and how you store those structures is up to you

Comment: @Ron I think OP needs them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334779/populating-a-vector-of-objects-within-a-class